# Public Images to public sites

Tags: data-export, excel

I create a page export my data to excel file, user download excel file.
In this file has some images, when i download file then open it.
when excel is opened, it will get images from my site.
Excel file can't get these images because log in is requred to download image.

I tried to upload these images in document tab to public it. in this [article](http://training.handsonconnect.org/m/site_customization/l/35011-getting-the-urls-for-documents-you-wish-to-make-available-for-download-on-the-public-site)

But in this, i only see "public with all users". 
So if any one want to see this image, they must log in.

**How can i get images to my excel file from salesforce??**

Comment: There is a check box which says Externally Available Image, did you checked that ?

Comment: Thanks Prabhat Kumar, I resoled my problem. 
I use chatter to share this file.  but I have many images. 
Do you have other ways?

Answer (score 0):

I resoled by post that images to chatter and public it.
This link can help: http://training.handsonconnect.org/m/site_customization/l/135164?data-resolve-url=true&data-manual-id=3429